# Using C# to search a CSV file and pull the value in the column next to it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, csv

I am trying to make a program I am writing (C# in Visual Studio) look up a value in an external CSV file, and pull the value in the next column back in to a label in my WinForm.

My CSV file, which is a test with dummy data, is:

```
> old,newuser,newpassword
> firstlinetomakesure,firstnewusername,firstnewpassword
> adslusernameplaintext,thisisthenewuser,andthisisthenewpassword
> hello,terion,nadiomn
> somethingdownhere,thisisthelastuser,andthisisthelastpassword 
> 11,12,13
> 21,22,23 
> 31,32,33
```

I have tried using the solution at the link below, but could only return the value in the second column of the last line.

[Search value in csv file using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557459/search-value-in-csv-file-using-c-sharp)

I've been trying to make the program search the "old" column for a value, then pull in the value from the "newuser" column on the matching row. This would then go onto a label in the WinForm.

Any example code or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code you already have.

Comment: This will do you good https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov I deleted the code I had in frustration I'm afraid. Sorry that's not helpful

Comment: Try `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`. It's amazing what they hide away in these Visual Basic namespaces...

Answer (score 2):

Use a CSV library for reading CSV files.  I like this one https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Reading CSV files is not as straightforward as it seems.  The number one difficulty is that values can have commas in them.  The steps are simply, make a C# class to hold your data, map it to the data you see in your CSV file, and call the CSV library.  That page I linked has enough examples to show you how to do this.

Comment: .Net actually contains a pretty good CSV reader... but they stupidly hid it in the Visual Basic namespace. It's called `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`.

Answer (score 0):

Get LinqToExcel Using the Nuget Package Manager Console
 Copy Code
PM> Install-Package LinqToExcel

```
void PrintArtistAlbums()
{
    string pathToExcelFile = ""
        + @"D:\Code\Blog Projects\BlogSandbox\ArtistAlbums.xlsx";

    string sheetName = "Sheet1";

    var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathToExcelFile);
    var artistAlbums = from a in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName) select a;

    foreach (var a in artistAlbums)
    {
        string artistInfo = "Artist Name: {0}; Album: {1}";
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(artistInfo, a["Name"], a["Title"]));
    }
}
```

Comment: He is using **csv** file while you have added code for **xlsx**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting one, natively available in .Net, but hidden away in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace: `TextFieldParser`. This can read the contents exactly like they are produced by MS Office, and it can even handle line breaks inside values.

```
public static List<String[]> SplitFile(String filePath, Encoding textEncoding, Char separator)
{
    String fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath, textEncoding);
    List<String[]> splitLines = new List<String[]>();
    try
    {
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(fileContents))
        using (TextFieldParser tfp = new TextFieldParser(sr))
        {
            tfp.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            tfp.Delimiters = new String[] { separator.ToString() };
            while (true)
            {
                String[] curLine = tfp.ReadFields();
                if (curLine == null)
                    break;
                splitLines.Add(curLine);
            }
        }
        return splitLines;
    }
    catch (MalformedLineException mfle)
    {
        throw new FormatException(String.Format("Could not parse line {0} in file {1}!", mfle.LineNumber, filePath));
    }
}
```

Comes with its own handy `MalformedLineException` when parsing fails.

You need to add `Microsoft.VisualBasic` to the project references, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one, [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source file helper library to load CSV file and find the item as below

```
string csv = @"old,newuser,newpassword
firstlinetomakesure,firstnewusername,firstnewpassword
adslusernameplaintext,thisisthenewuser,andthisisthenewpassword
hello,terion,nadiomn
somethingdownhere,thisisthelastuser,andthisisthelastpassword 
11,12,13
21,22,23 
31,32,33";

using (var p = new ChoCSVReader(new StringReader(csv))
    .WithFirstLineHeader()
    )
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Where(rec => rec.old == "hello").Select(rec => rec.newuser).First());
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.

Comment: Thanks for this. Gave it a go and the application kept exiting with error code -1. The WinForm never loaded and debug session terminated without any further details

Comment: Odd. can u try putting the below statement at the application startup and see any errors reported in the log file under log folder. `ChoETLFrxBootstrap.TraceLevel = System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Verbose;`